# Need to filter target table in SQL merge query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery SQL to execute a merge query. Here is the query

```
MERGE `dataset.target_table` AS Target
USING
    (
        select
            *
        from
            `dataset.source_table` s_data
        WHERE
            trans_id is not null and user_id is not null
    )
AS Source
ON Source.trans_id = Target.trans_id and Target.start_date IN 
    (
        select distinct start_date from `dataset.source_table`
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (...)
    VALUES (...)
WHEN MATCHED and Target.user_id is null THEN
    UPDATE SET ...
```

I am getting an issue with the using a subquery in the ON statement. `In Subquery not supported by join predicate`

The reason I have this subquery is because I want to filter the Target table before the Merge happens or bigquery throws a OOM exception.  The target table is 10billion rows while the source  is 200m rows.  I don't need the subquery in the ON statement, but it's a hacky way to esentially filter the Target table before the merge happens.  Is there some other approach I can take?

I tried the approach here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30633/merge-a-subset-of-the-target-table utilizing

```
WITH TARGET AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM `dataset.target_table`
    WHERE <filter target_table here>
)
MERGE INTO TARGET
...
```

but it seems this isn't supported by BigQuery and gave a syntax error.  How can I filter my Target table before the Merge happens so it doesn't need to load the entire table in memory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused.  Can you just take the `start_date` from the matching row in `source`?

```
MERGE `dataset.target_table` AS Target USING
       (select *
        from `dataset.source_table` s_data
        WHERE  trans_id is not null and user_id is not null
       ) AS Source
       ON Source.trans_id = Target.trans_id and
          Target.start_date = source.start_date
```

Comment: So the only reason I am adding the start_date portion is because its a hacky way to filter the target table before a join happens.  ` Target.start_date = source.start_date` this would still cause the full table to be loaded in memory for the join to happen.  If I had a condition in the ON statement that only applies to the target, it will apply that filter before attempting a join.  BigQuery can't handle loading the entire table in memory for a join to happen, so I added this logic to limit how much of the table has to be loaded into memory.